# Foreignkey is not updated with primarykey of child table

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have to tables a parent table and a child table that have a one-to-one relationship that I have created with entity framework in asp.net core mvc.
My problem is that when I insert data via a view or via an insert query into the tables the foreignkey column is 'null'.

parent table created with this code:

```
public class Profile
{
    [Key]
    public int ProfileId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string MainPositions { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string KeyCompetences { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string PersonalDetails { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Languages { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("EducationId")]
    public virtual Education Education { get; set; }
}
```

child table created with this code:

```
public class Education
{
    public int EducationId { get; set; }
    public string EducationTitle { get; set; }
    public string University { get; set; }
    public string Thesis { get; set; }

    public int ProfileId { get; set; }
}
```

This is the result: [image]

As you can see the ProfileId column (foreignkey) is 0 and and the EducationId column (foreignkey) is 'NULL'. I was expecting that the foreignkeys in both columns would be filled with the primary keys:
EducationId --> 14
ProfileId --> 8  So cross referencing each other.
Can anybody show me what Im am doing wrong here.

I created these table with asp.net core code first using entity framework 5.0

Screenshot6
[image]

---

```
@model CV_App_Core_V2.Models.Profile

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Profile</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="MainPosition" class="control-label"></label>
                @*<input asp-for="MainPositions" class="form-control" />*@
                <textarea asp-for="MainPosition" class="form-control" rows="2"></textarea>
                <span asp-validation-for="MainPosition" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="KeyCompetence" class="control-label"></label>
                @*<input asp-for="KeyCompetences" class="form-control" />*@
                @*<textarea class="form-control" id="KeyCompetences" rows="5" style="width:150%"></textarea>*@
                <textarea asp-for="KeyCompetence" class="form-control" rows="8" style="width:250%"></textarea>
                <span asp-validation-for="KeyCompetence" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="PersonalDetail" class="control-label"></label>
                @*<input asp-for="PersonalDetails" class="form-control" />*@
                <textarea asp-for="PersonalDetail" class="form-control" rows="5" style="width:125%"></textarea>
                <span asp-validation-for="PersonalDetail" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Language" class="control-label"></label>
                @*<input asp-for="Languages" class="form-control" />*@
                <textarea asp-for="Language" class="form-control" rows="2"></textarea>
                <span asp-validation-for="Language" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

---

```
@model CV_App_Core_V2.Models.Education

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Education</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="EducationTitle" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="EducationTitle" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="EducationTitle" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="University" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="University" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="University" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Thesis" class="control-label"></label>
                @*<input asp-for="Thesis" class="form-control" />*@
                <textarea asp-for="Thesis" class="form-control" rows="2" style="width:100%"></textarea>
                <span asp-validation-for="Thesis" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

---

```
using CV_App_Core_V2.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Text;

namespace CV_App_Core_V2.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {       
        }
        public DbSet<Profile> Profile { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Education> Education { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelbuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelbuilder);

            modelbuilder.Entity<Profile>()
                    .HasOne(x => x.Education)
                   .WithOne(i => i.Profile);                  
        }
    }
}
```

---

ProfileController -> Create

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ProfileId,Name,MainPosition,KeyCompetence,PersonalDetail,Language")] Profile profile)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(profile);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(profile);
}
```

---

EducationController -> Create

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("EducationId,EducationTitle,University,Thesis")] Education education)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {               
        _context.Add(education);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(education);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it was EF 5? (Not EF6 or EF Core?) What you look to be trying to set up is a 1-to-1 between Education and Profile. For EF6 and prior, 1-to-1 relationships use the PKs on both tables to link them together. While you have a Profile ID on Education, you have no relationship (navigation property or apparent mapping) back to Profile.

The first thing to check is whether you want a 1-to-1 relationship or a many-to-1 relationship.

1-to-1: A profile can have only 1 education, and an education can have only 1 profile.
many-to-1: A profile can have only 1 education, and that education can be associated to many profiles.

For a 1-to-1 relationship in EF5/6 your Education record would have a ProfileId as it's PK.

```
public class Profile
{
    [Key]
    public int ProfileId { get; set; }
    // ...
    public virtual Education Education { get; set; }
}

public class Education
{
    [Key]
    public int ProfileId { get; set; }
    // ...
    public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Profile>()
    .HasRequired(x => x.Education)
    .WithRequired(x => x.Profile);
```

The PK in Education can be named whatever you want, but the mapping in EF will join on the PKs. For this reason I recommend using the same name to avoid confusion. EF Core I believe accommodates 1-to-1 relationships with nominating FKs on one/both tables.

A many-to-1 relationship is easy to set up. A profile will have a single Education, and we can opt to either have Education reference back to the Profiles, or not:

```
public class Profile
{
    [Key]
    public int ProfileId { get; set; }
    // ...
    [ForeignKey("Education")]
    public int EducationId { get; set; }
    public virtual Education Education { get; set; }
}

public class Education
{
    [Key]
    public int ProfileId { get; set; }
    // ...
    // Optional...
    public virtual ICollection<Profile> Profiles { get; set; } = new List<Profile>();
}
```

then to map:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Profile>()
    .HasRequired(x => x.Education)
    .WithMany(x => x.Profiles);
```

If you don't need the reference from Education back to the profiles, you can remove that collection from Education, then update the mapping to:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Profile>()
    .HasRequired(x => x.Education)
    .WithMany();
```

A good example of this might be having an Order that references an OrderType. We never really need to load an OrderType and see a list of orders that reference it so there doesn't need to be a collection of Orders there. We can still always load all orders of a particular type by using something like:

```
var submittedOrders = context.Orders.Where(x => x.OrderStatusId == OrderStatuses.Submitted); // Where OrderStatuses = Constant/enum of status IDs as an example.
```

Update: For EF Core you can set up 1-to-1 relationships much like a 1-to-many with nominated FKs, however you need to instruct EF explicitly that the relationship is to be treated as a 1-to-1.:

```
public class Profile
{
    [Key]
    public int ProfileId { get; set; }
    // ...
    [ForeignKey("EducationId")] // Shadow property.
    public virtual Education Education { get; set; }
}

public class Education
{
    [Key]
    public int EducationId { get; set; }
    // ...
    [ForeignKey("ProfileId")] // Shadow Property.
    public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the mapping: (may be required explicitly to avoid EF assuming 1-to-manys)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Profile>()
    .HasOne(x => x.Education)
    .WithOne(x => x.Profile);
```

The examples for EF Core 5 look to be set up similarly, except without the EducationId on the Profile table, it just looks like a 1-to-many relationship with a ProfileId on Education. However they add an explicit mapping as 1-to-1.

(see: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-one-relationship-configuration)

Update:
Ok, based on your persistence code, the issue looks to be that you are not tracking the information needed to link the two entities. You have two calls, one to save a Profile, and one to Save an Education. The Education save method does not appear to have any details being sent to indicate which Profile it should be associated to.

Given:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ProfileId,Name,MainPosition,KeyCompetence,PersonalDetail,Language")] Profile profile)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(profile);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(profile);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("EducationId,EducationTitle,University,Thesis")] Education education)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {               
        _context.Add(education);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(education);
}
```

If a new Profile is saved first, that `Create(Profile)` should be fine. However, when you go to save the Education, at a minimum that Create method will require the ProfileId that the education is being saved under:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(int ProfileId, [Bind("EducationId,EducationTitle,University,Thesis")] Education education)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {               
        var profile = _context.Profiles.Single(x => x.ProfileId == profileId);
        education.Profile = profile;
        profile.Education = education;
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(education);
}
```

Basically we need to fetch the Profile by ID, then rather than just adding the Education to the DbContext, which doesn't associate anything with each other, we fetch the Profile by ID and associate the two together then call `SaveChanges`.

One thing to note about EF entities and passing them between client and server. What you get back from the client is *not* an entity, even if you had loaded an entity earlier and sent it to the client. It is a deserialized block of data in an Entity's skin. The DbContext you use when performing updates/adds will not be tracking that instance, and you have to be careful because it may be tracking another instance of that same entity which can lead to unexpected errors. Treat any "entity" class coming from the client as a block of data that the DbContext cannot trust.

Comment: Hi Steve Py, Im still a newbe learning. Thanks for your answer. I found out it was EF core 5.0.

Comment: What I really want is that when I enter data in Profiles table en then in de Education table I want them linked so that I can present them both in a single view. I was looking whether it was possible that the ProfileId could be inserted as foreignkey in the Education table. For example if the ProfileId is 8, then I want to see that in de foreignkey column in Education as 8.

Comment: Ok, EF Core 5 makes more sense. :) I've updated the answer with details about a 1-to-1 relationship with EF Core. It's pretty much set up as a 1-to-many but with an explicit `HasOne`/`WithOne` mapping.

Comment: I updated my code and did the migration and db update. When I run the application and enter data I see that the ProfieId column in Education table has the value 'NULL' and the foreignkey in table Profile is also 'NULL'. See screenshot 6 above

Comment: Can you add the code where you create and add the Profile and associated Education and save them to the DbContext?

Comment: Do you mean the codes of the views and the AplicationDBcontext?

Comment: Just the controller call where you create the Profile and Education entity you are trying to add, add them to the DbContext and SaveChanges. Wherever that occurs. I'm guessing this would be ProfileController.Create(model) or ProfileController.Index(model)

Comment: I have add them above.

Comment: Ok, I think I see the problem. I have updated the answer above to outline the potential change you need to associate these entities.

Comment: I get this exception: An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements. It says this code gives the exception --> var profile = _context.Profiles.Single(x => x.ProfileId == ProfileId);

Comment: This means that when you are creating an Education record, you haven't passed a Profile ID from when the profile was created. After a Profile is saved you redirect using ` return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));` What is required is that when you load your list of profiles or are on a Profile detail page and go to create an Education, you need to provide the Education view with the Profile ID you will associate. Without that, how will the server know which Profile the Education will be associated with?  It's probably just resolving a default Int value of 0 resulting in no Profile record.

Comment: I found the solution. The problem was in the create view of the education controller. The asp-for tag should have been ProfileId instead of Profile.
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ProfileId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="ProfileId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ProfileId"></select>
            </div>